# I want to upload photo on facebook from apex controller?

Tags: upload

I am doing integration salesforce with facebook. I want to upload photo on facebook first i made a visualforce page and apex page and after authentication now i want's to upload photo on facebook i write below code i got one error

> {"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload
>   file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}

---

```
        String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file);

        System.debug('------------------------------------------'+bodyEncoded);
        String boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C';  


         String body=boundary + '\r\n'+
        'Content-Disposition:form-data;name="source";filename="'+filename+'"\r\n'+
        'Content-Type: '+filetype+'\r\n'+
         bodyEncoded +'\r\n' +
         boundary;


        System.debug('----------------------------------body is-------------\n'+body);
        HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setbody(body);

       // req.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache') ;
          req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary="'+boundary+'"'); 
          req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(body.length()));
          req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/photos?access_token='+accesstoken);
          HttpResponse res = null;
          http h= new Http();
          res= h.send(req);    
          system.debug( '------------upload photo----------------------'+res.getbody());
```

how i can upload photo on facebook ?thanks sir

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Facebook's /{user-id}/photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos) you have two format choices for the file data that the error message is complaining about:

- source - using multipart/form-data encoding
- url - a public http URL

You seem to be trying the first approach. I don't know if it is possible to encode the image bytes appropriately using Apex for this to work - perhaps someone who has succeeded (or failed) can comment.

The second format could be used instead by first copying the image to [an "Externally Available Image" Document](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005050&language=en_US), and sending the URL of that and so avoiding any awkward encoding of the image bytes.